# Assign complex object to user control in markup

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, webforms

I can do this in code-behind, but I'm looking for a lazy way of doing this in the markup itself:

Suppose I have a UserControl with a complex property:

```
public class MyControl : UserControl {
    public Person Someone { get; set; }
}
```

And I have a page with this control:

```
<uc1:MyControl id="my1" runat="server" />
```

I want to put a person into this control from the page markup, not the code-behind. In code-behind, it would look something like:

```
my1.Someone = GetSomePerson();
```

I'd like to do:

```
<uc1:MyControl id="my1" runat="server" Someone="<%= GetSomePerson() %>" />
```

but that's not valid. Any suggestions on how to do this? I think I can do it one property at a time, but I'm looking for a more generic approach - the complex object I'm passing in is much bigger than this example (dozens of properties), so I don't want to define them all individually in the markup even if I could.

I'm wondering if there's some kind of magic `<%$ %>` function that will do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<uc1:MyControl id="my1" runat="server" />
<% my1.Someone = GetSomePerson(); %>
```

or since this clearly wasn't the answer you were looking for...

```
<uc1:MyControl id="my1" runat="server" someParameter="uniqueId" />
```

And then inside the uc1 control

```
public string someParameter;
Someone = GetSomePerson(someParameter);
```

Comment: Thanks - a couple of good ideas, but I'm actually trying to avoid having a code-behind at all.

Comment: You don't need to use a separate code-behind file at all; just include  server tags `<% %>` or do `<script runat="server"></script>`

Comment: Yep, I think I'm going to go with your original suggestion, even though I did find a way to do it (see my answer).

Comment: Stupid page lifecycle...FYI: This solution requires a bit of a tweak - the assignment has to go above the control declaration, not below it. And then it only works for inline ASP.NET expressions, like `<%= Someone.Name %>`. If you attempt to access `Someone` in `Page_Load` of the control, it hasn't been assigned yet - you'd have to assign it in `Page_Load` of the page to get things assigned in the right order.

Answer (score 3):

I found someone who implemented exactly what I was looking for:

http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/09/The-CodeExpressionBuilder.aspx

After including some code and a new expression builder in web.config, you can do this by using an ASP.NET expression:

```
<uc1:MyControl runat="server" Someone="<%$ Code:GetSomePerson() %>" />
```

I don't think I'll do it in my current project, since it's not really a standard. I'm sure people would be totally bad-mouth me down the road when they're looking at the code and trying to figure out what I did - but it's definitely good to know for the future.

**EDIT**

For posterity, just in case this link doesn't work forever, here's the relevant code:

```
// C#:
[ExpressionPrefix("Code")]
public class CodeExpressionBuilder : ExpressionBuilder {
    public override CodeExpression GetCodeExpression(BoundPropertyEntry entry, 
       object parsedData, ExpressionBuilderContext context) {
        return new CodeSnippetExpression(entry.Expression);
    }
}

// Web.config:
<compilation debug="true">
  <expressionBuilders>
    <add expressionPrefix="Code" type="Infinity.Web.Compilation.CodeExpressionBuilder"/>
  </expressionBuilders>
</compilation>

// ASP.NET .aspx:
<asp:CheckBox id="chk1" runat="server" Text="<%$ Code: DateTime.Now %>" />
```